# How to read one stream into another?

Tags: java

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(myFile);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

Question: How can I read everything from `in` into `out` in a way which is not a hand-crafted loop with my own byte buffer?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Write one method to do this, and call it from everywhere which needs the functionality. [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) already has code for this, in [`ByteStreams.copy`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)). I'm sure just about any other library with "general" IO functionality has it too, but Guava's my first "go-to" library where possible. It rocks :)

Comment: The `ByteStreams` is annoted as `@Beta` is that not an issue?

Comment: @gabuzo: That depends on just how risk averse you are. I suspect that it's very unlikely that that method call will change, and I'm sure the implementation is fine.

Comment: Even if it changes or disappears, you only risk to have to fix it in case you upgrade. The method is simple and the source code available (even as subversion repo).

Answer (score 44):

Java 9 (and later) answer ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-)):

```
in.transferTo(out);
```

Seems they finally realized that this functionality is so commonly needed that it’d better be built in. The method returns the number of bytes copied in case you need to know.

Answer (score 20):

In [Apache Commons / IO](http://commons.apache.org/io), you can do it using [`IOUtils.copy(in, out)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream%2C%20java.io.OutputStream%29):

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(myFile);
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```

But I agree with Jon Skeet, I'd rather use Guava's [`ByteStreams.copy(in, out)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)

Answer (score 13):

So what Guava's ByteStreams.copy(in, out) does:

```
  private static final int BUF_SIZE = 0x1000; // 4K

  public static long copy(InputStream from, OutputStream to)
      throws IOException {
    checkNotNull(from);
    checkNotNull(to);
    byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
    long total = 0;
    while (true) {
      int r = from.read(buf);
      if (r == -1) {
        break;
      }
      to.write(buf, 0, r);
      total += r;
    }
    return total;
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

In my project I used this method:

```
private static void copyData(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws Exception {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}
```

Comment: It may helpful to others if you explain why your code is different and how it fixes the issue

Comment: Concise code and not using libraries.

Comment: Just short and simple code without any dependencies, pure java

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Guava one could use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.html) (old), and [Apache Commons IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) (new as advised in the comment).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the loop, instead of importing new classes, or adding libraries to my project. The library function is probably also implemented with a loop. But that's just my personal taste.

However, my question to you: what are you trying to do? Think of the "big picture", if you want to put the entire contents of a file into a byte array, why not just do that? The size of the arrray is file.length(), and you don't need it to dynamically grow, hidden behind a ByteArrayOutputStream (unless your file is shared, and its contents can change while you read).

Another alternative: could you use a FileChannel and a ByteBuffer (java.nio)?