# How to pass getClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() value to FileOutputStream

Tags: java, io, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, filestreamresult

I am using `getClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.txt")` which returns of type Inputstream, to get the filepath which works fine. Now i need to pass the the filepath to streamresult but it has a constructor : `StreamResult(new FileOutputStream())`. How do i pass the filepath which is of type inputstream to to streamresult.

I am reading an xml file and displaying that data in a jsp file. From the jsp file i am setting a flag which writes data back to the xml file. `TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(ds.getOwnerDocument()), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(pathFile)));`. So pathFile is the file to which i want to write data to. I just cannot pass abc.txt in place of pathFile because i need the absoulte file path.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Read a file? Or write a file?

Comment: Looks like you need to copy `abc.txt` to another place, right?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: It is that simple: Using `getResoureceAsStrream()` means, the file is stored somewhere in the classpath. This means it is read-only. You cannot modify it. You have to save the file to another place, as @Andriy Kryvtsun suggested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read one stream into another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919690/how-to-read-one-stream-into-another)